# set ACL for BackupUser

Tags: linux, access-control-list

I want to backup a whole bunch of folders from different users remotely. Therefore I created a special user that is able to log into the machine and (should) have the right to read all the files via a acl.

What I have done so far is to add these acls to the home directory

```
sudo setfacl -R -m d:u:backupuser:r-X /home
sudo setfacl -R -m u:backupuser:r-X /home
```

I thought that all new files will inherit the acl from the parent folder and the backupuser is therefore able to read all files and all new files. What really happens that some new files are not readable by the backupuser. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACLS use the group permissions as a mask *against* what is set.

Thus, if you have a acls of

```
u:backupuser:r-X
```

But a mode of:

```
rwx------
```

Then the ACL will not function correctly. If the mode was:

```
rwx--x---
```

Then this would allow `backupuser` traversal only access to the directory.

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought it was "X" (Capital) , as I had thought it should be the small x. But then I tried it out here on a directory and it was working. So I dont understand why its not working for you.

Another doubt I have is about the default mask value set. Take a look at getfacl's output for /home.

**Suggestion:** Using a backup system is a lot easier to manage if you have a network of systems to be backed up. I suggest AMANDA as I have used it for a few years at my small network.